# How to install keyboard module without pip?

Tags: python, module, keyboard, pypi

so I'm trying to install the keyboard module on a raspberry pi, but I can't use pip. Is there a way I can install it in a way that works? So far I have tried installing the extracted zip file from the pypi website, but nothing, not even the example code, works. I have attached a picture of what error I am getting when running the example code that comes in the folder. Thanks anyone for your help. Error message:

[image]

Comment: why do you can't use `pip`?

Comment: problem can be system which may block access to keyboard for security reason. On my Linux Mint I had problem to use `keyboard` or `pynput` without root privileges. And your error can also means that it can't access device `kbd`. As I remeber it needed to add user to special group in system which gives access to keyboard - but I don't remeber what group it was.